# Overlay around annotation

Tags: swift, annotations, mkoverlay, mkcircle

Hi I'm trying to create an overlay around my annotations, like apples reminders app, I have already created an MKCircle object which I think I should use to show the overlay but how do I convert my MKCircle object into an MKOVerlay object? maybe there's a better way to add annotations? I'm new to swift and programming. Any suggestions?

Comment: oh I got some error before but it seems to work now, but how do I get the MKCircle to show around the annotation? mapView.add(overlay) don't seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MKCircle` is a `MKOverlay` object. You just need to add it as an overlay:

```
let circle = MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: 1000)
mapView.add(circle)
```

Of course, you have to tell the map how to render it by implementing [`mapView(_:rendererFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452203-mapview) in your delegate and instantiate a `MKCircleRenderer` for the `MKCircle` that’s passed as an overlay.

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.cyan.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        return renderer
    }
}
```

Clearly, make sure you specified the `delegate` for your `MKMapView`, too. And if you have other types of renderers, you might implement specific logic for those, too, e.g.

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let circle = overlay as? MKCircle {
            let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(circle: circle)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.cyan.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            return renderer
        }

        if let polygon = overlay as? MKPolygon {
            let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: polygon)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            return renderer
        }

        if let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            return renderer
        }

        fatalError("Unexpected overlay type")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi so I added the first code to my program but it don't seem to work. When is the renderFor function called? I found from the documentation it's called when "The renderer object is responsible for drawing the contents of your overlay when asked to do so by the map view. " How do I ask the render object to draw? Sorry if I ask stupid questions

Comment: It's called for you automatically if the overlay overlaps with the visible portion of the map. The only trick is to make sure to set the `delegate` of the map view. You can either do this in IB, or in `viewDidLoad` with `mapView.delegate = self`.

Comment: hey any ideas if I want to add a handle on the overlay object to be able to resize the radius?